# R programming: what are the less obvious differences between x and print(x)

Tags: r

I've been going through some courses on R, and something feels a bit glossed over.

When introducing if else, the form is

```
if (condition){
     (expression)
}
```

And usually, (expression) looks like print(x)

Is there any specific reason in this case to prefer print(x) over just x in this case? Before this point in most materials, usually you just plant x in there, and it would produce the object, print it to the console and such.

Looking ahead to writing files for example I could see it being useful, like T versus print(T) maybe, but if somebody could lay out the reasoning for this seeming preference in conditionals, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The print function has different arguments that might be useful when printing the results....

Comment: `if`-`else` control flow blocks are typically used inside functions. When working interactively, `print` and `x` evaluate the same. Inside a function they do not.